# SQL Server Query Explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on code from a person who held my position 2+ years ago, and am having trouble deciphering a block of their SQL code.

```
WHERE  ACCOUNT NOT IN (SELECT ACCOUNT
                   FROM   MWAPPTS A1
                   WHERE  A1.ACCOUNT = A.ACCOUNT
                          AND ADATE > dbo.Endofmonth(ACTIONDATE)
                          AND REASON IN ('CPE','NPPE')
                          AND USERFLAG IN ( 'U', 'B' ))
```

`dbo.Endofmonth` is a stored procedure which gets the last day of the month for the inputed date.

If I am reading that right, we are not including rows where the account would be returned by the select statement shown. I am having problems with the select statement though. Am I correct that it is getting `ACCOUNT` where `ADATE` is older than the end of the month. The reason IS "CPE" or "NPPE", and the `USERFLAG` is either "U", or "B"?

Comment: While an end-of-month function is handy, you're better off using lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive style dates - ie using `aDate >= dbo.StartOfMonth(actionDate)`; this would also make it easier for you to compare against timestamps and the like.  I'm also rather curious about the rest of the statement, as I can't shake the feeling that there are potential optimizations available.  Oh - don't suffix column names with datatypes, name it so it's type is obvious, say, `actionOccurredOn` or similar (I'm aware you probably can't change the database).

Comment: @X-Zero I wish I could post the entire SP so that you could see how terrible it is, but unfortunately it's medial in nature and thus protected by HIPPA. All the code that I inherited is so bad, I'd go as far as call it laughable.

Comment: I'm not a legal adviser/lawyer, but I didn't think _source code_ was covered.  Obviously **data** is, and shouldn't be actually shared (although it could potentially be anonymized first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are returning the records where the account does not have the following:

1) an `ADATE` greater than the date returned by the function `dbo.Endofmonth(ACTIONDATE)`.

2) a `Reason` that is `CPE or NPPE`

3) and the `Userflag` is either `U or B`.

You would have to look at the code in the function `dbo.Endofmonth(ACTIONDATE)` to determine exactly what it is returning.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct that it is getting ACCOUNT where ADATE is older than the end of the month.

The inner `SELECT` itself is looking for entries where `ADATE` is *after* the end of the month from `ACTIONDATE`. The `NOT IN` in the outer `SELECT`should then retrieve rows where the account's `ADATE` is `<=` the end of the month from `ACTIONDATE`.

Your other assumptions seem correct.

Aside: It seems `dbo.Endofmonth` is a User-Defined Function, not a stored procedure (or it wouldn't be possible to call it like that).